# how can I add an URL parameter to a rest route using register_rest_route()?

Tags: rest-api

I would like to add a REST route that would looks like

> .../v1/import/?url=XXX

where XXX is an URL.

I had a try with

```
register_rest_route('.../v1','import/?url=(?:/(?P<url>\w+))?', array(
        array(
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'            => array( $this, 'import_url' ),
            'args' => array(
                'url' => array(
                    //'validate_callback' => array($this, 'validateImportUrl')
                ),
            ),
        )
    ) );
```

but it does not work:

> {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL
>   and request method","data":{"status":404}}

Can anyone help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Query parameters don't belong in the route, they should be added as arguments, which you've already done.

Answer (score -1):

Regex problem, I found out :)

```
register_rest_route( '.../v1', 'import(?:/?url=(?P<url>\d+))?', array(
```